InstaPy is having trouble finding the login elements on Instagram's page
InstaPy is having trouble finding the login elements on Instagram's page, likely due to changes in Instagram's front-end HTML structure. Instagram frequently updates its site, which can cause automated tools like InstaPy to fail when they can't find the expected HTML elements.
# imports
from instapy import InstaPy
from instapy import smart_run

# login credentials
insta_username = ""  # <- enter username here
insta_password = ""  # <- enter password here

# get an InstaPy session!
# set headless_browser=True to run InstaPy in the background
session = InstaPy(username=insta_username,
                  password=insta_password,
                  headless_browser=False,  # Set True to run in background
                  want_check_browser=False)  # Added as per community suggestion to fix login issue

with smart_run(session):
    """ Activity flow """
    # general settings
    session.set_relationship_bounds(enabled=True,
                                    delimit_by_numbers=True,
                                    max_followers=4590,
                                    min_followers=45,
                                    min_following=77)

    session.set_dont_include(["friend1", "friend2", "friend3"])
    session.set_dont_like(["pizza", "#store"])
    
    # activity
    session.like_by_tags(["natgeo"], amount=10)
    
    # Unfollowing
    session.unfollow_users(amount=10, nonFollowers=True, style="FIFO", unfollow_after=48 * 60 * 60)

Can someone help me please?
